# React and Type script createContext initial data for functions

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase, react-hooks, react-context

I have a context that is used to create, update, list and delete a set of data.

It is created as follows with the following types to be returned.

```
type TDataContext = {
    loading: boolean,
    getDataList: () => TData[],
    addNewData : (data: TData) => Promise<boolean> ,
    editData: (dataId: string, data: TData) => Promise<boolean>, 
    deleteData: (dataId: string) => Promise<boolean>, 
}

const ADataContext = createContext<TGymClientDataContext>({
    // How to initialize these here ?
})

export const ADataProvider: FC<{}> = ({children}) => {

    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)
    const [snapshot, loading, error] = useCollection<TDataStore>(db.collection(FIRESTORE_COLLECTIONS.DATA_COLLECTION), {});

    const getDataList = async (): TData[] => {
        if(loading == true) {
            return []
        }
        if(typeof snapshot == "undefined"){
            return []
        }
        return snapshot?.docs.map((item) => {
            const fetched = item.data();
    
            return ({
                id: item.id,
                doj: fetched.doj.toDate(),
                firstName: fetched.firstName,
                lastName: fetched.lastName,
            })
    
        })
    } 

    //    ... Function definitions

    
    const values = {
        loading,
        getDataList,
        addNewData,
        editData,
        deleteData,
    }

    return <ADataContext.Provider value={values}>
        {children}
    </ADataContext.Provider>

}


export const useDataHook = () => useContext(ADataContext)
```

1. I would like to know what will be the good possible way to pass initial data to createContext ?

I'm creating this with the following usage to be expected

```
const {loading, getClientList, editClientData, addNewClient, deleteClientData} = useGymClient()
```

The functions are simply expected to return true or false depending on the operations being successful or not.

Another question is,

2. The data has to be always caught via getDataList function.
   is directly passing the snapshot variable down better approach ? In that case, what will be a better initializer for the create context